# Injecting a service using a method instead of the constructor

Tags: angular, angular5

Say I have this service and component. I would like to use multiple instances of MySillyService.

```
@Injectable()
export class MySillyService {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})


export class AppComponent {

  vals: Array<MySillyService>;

  constructor() {

    this.vals = [1,2,3].map(v => {
       return this.getSillyService();
    });

  }

  @Inject(MySillyService)
  getSillyService(mss: MySillyService){
    console.log('getting mss...');
    return mss;
  }

}
```

this won't compile because I get this error:

[image]

Is there a way to inject a new instance of a service using a method instead of the constructor?

Comment: What is the reason for trying this? Does your MySillyService instance change at run-time?

Comment: I want to inject multiple instances of MySillyService, I do not want to re-use the same instance. Makes sense?

Comment: @ConnorsFan has the right idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Injector](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#appendix-working-with-injectors-directly) service can be used to inject a service using a method:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {

    vals: Array<MySillyService>;
    mySillyService: MySillyService;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
       this.vals = ['some','dynamic','array'].map(v => this.getSillyService());
    }

    getSillyService() {
       return this.injector.get(MySillyService);
    }

    injectAnotherInstance() {
       this.mySillyService = this.injector.get(MySillyService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need Angular's management of the instances (single instance) or its dependency injection, you could create just a simple class. Then you can create and pass around how ever many instances of it that you need.

I don't think this is a common technique ... but it should work.

Comment: I think @ConnorsFan has the right idea, not sure if this is best practice, but it answers the question I think

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. But you can inject multiple instances just by naming them different things:

constructor(private myService1: dataService, private myService2: dataService) { }

Comment: yeah the problem is that the `[1,2,3]` array is in fact a dynamically sized array, so I can't hardcode the constructor like that

Comment: Ah okay. Gotcha. In that case, I'm not sure how to do it :( but now i'm curious to find out! lol

Comment: I think @ConnorsFan has the answer